# Jquery slider in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, slider

I have 3 images-myimage1,myimage2 and myimage3. When i click on each image i get a set of slides-slider,slider2 and slider3 which in turn is in container1,container2 and container2 respectively.This is my HTML:

```
    <div id="right">
    <img id="myimage1" onclick="changeimage1()"  src="images/build_i.png"  />
    <img id="myimage2" onclick="changeimage2()"  src="images/apply_i.png"  />
    <img id="myimage3" onclick="changeimage3()"  src="images/learn_i.png"  />
    </div> 
     <div id="PicInRight"> <div id="container1" > <div id="slider" > <ul><li><img      id="Img" src='slide_intro.png'/></li></ul> </div></div> <div id="container2"> <div id="slider2" > <ul><li><img id="Img" src='slide1.png' /></li></ul> </div></div> <div id="container3"> <div id="slider3" > <ul><li><img id="Img" src='slide1.png' /></li></ul> </div> </div></div>
```

In the head section, i have hidden the containers which have the slides in them.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#container1").hide();
    $("#container2").hide();
    $("#container3").hide();
    });
     </script>
```

In my Javascript the on click function goes like this:

```
      function changeimage1()
     {

    $("#container2").hide();
    $("#container3").hide();
    $("#container1").show();
    $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: false, 
            continuous: true
        });
        }
```

and so on for myimage1 and myimage2.

```
    function changeimage2()
    {   $("#container1").hide();
    $("#container3").hide();
    $("#container2").show();


        $("#slider2").easySlider({
            auto: false, 
            continuous: true
        });
    }

     function changeimage3()
    {           
$("#container1").hide();
    $("#container2").hide();
$("#container3").show();
$("#slider3").easySlider({
            auto: false, 
            continuous: true
        });
}
```

Now, this works fine only if i click on myimage3 first. The sliders show and work fine.When i click on image1 and image2 later they work too.
But if i click on myimage1 first , only the first slider work.when i click on myimage2 and myimage3 later, the sliders in container2 and 3 only show but do not change over on click of next and previous!
Similar case if i click on myimage2 first.
Why is this happening and what should i do to correct it?

Comment: You should post your whole code (including `changeimage2` and `changeimage3`), and creating a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a good idea. Also, I don't see any HTML5 tags here, so I'm not sure mentioning "HTML5" is useful. Finally, there's this [easy to use and customize jQuery slider plugin](http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider) I created if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: does all the container have id slider in it?

Comment: @Kardarp Patel -container1 2 and 3 are also ids.In that there are sliders with ids -slider,slider2 and slider3.

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting!@Pioul-Thanks for the slider. I shall use that as the last resort.

Comment: u can edit your post, far more easier for formating

Comment: I still cant understand how it works only if i click on myimage1 first!